# rsync: inclusion of only specific directories does not always work

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

I am writing a script to create incremental backups with `rsync`. I have an includes file to only include specific directories of a sub-directory. The rest should be excluded. Everything works as expected with the source directory I am testing with, but it does not when I try to actually backup my files to my external drive.

Here is the script so far:

```bash
SOURCE_DIR="$HOME/"
DEST_DIR="/Volumes/Stuff/Backup/"

if [ ! -d "$SOURCE_DIR" ]; then
    echo "\"${SOURCE_DIR}\" does not exist."; exit
elif [ ! -d "$DEST_DIR" ]; then
    echo "\"${DEST_DIR}\" does not exist."; exit
fi

PARENT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)"
DIR_NAME="$(date '+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')"
BACKUP_DIR="$DEST_DIR/$DIR_NAME"
LATEST_LINK="$DEST_DIR/latest"
INCLUDE_FILE="$PARENT_DIR/include.txt"

mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR"

rsync -av \
  --delete \
  --prune-empty-dirs \
  --include-from="$INCLUDE_FILE" \
  --link-dest="$LATEST_LINK" \
  "$SOURCE_DIR" \
  "$BACKUP_DIR"

rm -f "$LATEST_LINK"
ln -s "$BACKUP_DIR" "$LATEST_LINK"

echo "Size of current backup:" "$(du -sh "$BACKUP_DIR")"
echo "Size of all backups:" "$(du -sh "$DEST_DIR")"
```

The file `include.txt` has the following content:

```
- .DS_Store
- /Downloads/
+ /Library/
+ /Library/Application Support/***
+ /Library/Preferences/***
- /Library/***
```

The paths in `include.txt` are relative to the source directory I assume. Basically I want to back up my home directory, but exclude `Downloads` and everything in `Library` except its sub-directories `Application Support` and `Preferences`.

I already searched for an answer and as far as I understood it, some had similar problems, but the include file looks alright. And it works with the test directories. Where do I have it wrong?

I expected `Downloads` and everything in `Library` except its sub-directories `Application Support` and `Preferences` to be excluded, but they are always being included. I changed `includes.txt` because at first it did not work at all. Now it does work when I  backup from `$HOME/backup/test-source/` to `$HOME/backup/test-dest` but not when I actually want to backup from `$HOME/` to `/Volumes/Stuff/Backup/`.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Does adding the flag `--delete-excluded` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the specifications in your "**include-from**" file.

There should be **no leading /** for relative path references.

Note that the "*******" in *exlude patterns* **does not block creation** of the *parent directory*, only the files contained.

Also, the **excludes or includes need to be presented in the order of precedence**, which rule overrides subsequent rules, to ensure that those don't get ignored ... because they might fall under the scope of the preceding include/exclude (i.e. **+ Library/** in your original overrides the **-Library/***** ).

Your file should have the following contents:

```
- Downloads/***
- Downloads
+ Library/Application Support/***
+ Library/Preferences/***
- Library/***
+ *
+ .*
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late reply. I think it has to be the other way around. Because I want to *exclude* `Downloads/`. I also want to *exclude* `Library/` except for its sub-directories `Library/Preferences` and `Library/Application Support`.
Regarding the leading `/` at the beginning of a rule `man rsync | less -p "^FILTER RULES"` states that `/foo` would only match a file named "foo" at the root of the transaction. That's why I included it. Otherwise any directory "Library" would be excluded everywhere in the hierarchy with the rule `- Library/` right?

Comment: Also from the manual pages: "As the list of files/directories to transfer  is  built,  rsync  checks each  name  to  be transferred against the list of include/exclude patterns in turn, and the first matching pattern is acted on:  if it is an exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include pattern then that filename is not skipped; if no  matching  pattern  is  found, then the filename is not skipped."
Maybe `+ /Library/` is matching first and thus the whole directory is being included. After the match other rules are ignored. But if I omit that, `Library` isnt included at all

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you've been really helpful. It's really embarrassing, but I fear I haven't been clear about what I want to back up. I want to backup everything in `$HOME` except `$HOME/Downloads`. In general I also want to exclude `$HOME/Library` with the exception of `$HOME/Library/Application Support` and `$HOME/Library/Preferences`. These two sub-directories I need to be included, but everything else in `$HOME/Library` should be skipped. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: The leading `/` were indeed the problem here. Although the manual pages are confusing then in this regard, because it states that paths with a leading `/` are always considered relative to the root of the transfer. So I don't get why it would make a difference in this case. Also  when you exclude a folder with `- Whatever/` wouldn't this mean that both *Whatever/* and *Dir/Whatever/* would be excluded? Whereas using `- /Whatever/` would exclude *Whatever/* but not *Dir/Whatever* because the latter is not at the root of the transfer directory?

Comment: Updated answer again per your latest clarification of what you want to cover under ${HOME}.

Comment: @fruitsalad Yes, you want to start with `/` to anchor the pattern and avoid unintentionally matching nested folders.